# How to download XML file from server on click button?

Tags: php, html, xml, download

I have link to XML file, which locate on the server. When user click button, he must take dialog to save XML file to local disk. I'm determine link to XML file in "a href", but browser opened this file, not save. If i "save link as.." all OK. Help me please to solve this problem.

Update:
Server - IIS.
XML files create dynamically.
onClick event i send to js link to my XML file, js POST link to php using ajax. How modify my php to open "Save Dialog" to save XML file ?
js:

```
 function funk(url)
    {
    var ajax = getRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4)
        {
         ...
        }
    }
    ajax.open("POST", "/do_query.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = 'info='+url;
    ajax.send(data);
    }
```

php (do_query.php):

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['info'])) 
  {
    $info = $_POST['info'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: With PHP, you can do it, yes, but I don't understand what you're doing with Ajax. I strongly suspect that Ajax will ignore `Content-Disposition` headers. Perhaps you could describe that in a bit more detail?

Comment: How to return to the user save dialog ? Help me please.

Comment: Problem solved ! Thank's all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041355/how-to-save-dynamically-xml-file-from-server-to-a-local-machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XML file should be served with the HTTP header `Content-Disposition: attachment`. This tells the browser to download the file instead of opening it. Of course, the `Content-Type` header must also be set appropriately (`application/xml` is the generic XML mime type). How you add HTTP headers depends on your server configuration: please edit your question to add some details.

In Apache `.htaccess`, it's

```
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```

In other servers, it'll vary.

Comment: Did you read my answer? I told you how to do it with .htaccess in Apache; I told you that it would be different in other servers; and I asked you to edit your question to clarify which server you're using.

Comment: Ah, for IIS I don't know. (By the way, **edit the server you're using into the question; don't leave that information buried in comments**.) Also edit the question to clarify that this is a **static XML file**, not dynamic XML data, and then flag the question for reopening (it's not a dupe, and isn't answered by the other question).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to make a php file that you link to, and have that php file contain something like

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=blah.xml;');
readfile('blah.xml');
```

that should force the file to be seen as a download.

Comment: could the downvoter tell me why they downvoted?  I've used this kind of code before without issue...

Comment: Wasn't me either. But perhaps they knew `Content-Disposition` has had compatibility issues. The *easiest* and most compatible way is `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

Comment: @PointedEars: "perhaps they knew Content-Disposition has had compatibility issues" - reference?